# Fix racket indentation in VSCode?

Tags: racket

I'm using VSCode as my racket IDE, and while all the code compiles, none of the indentation features work.

I've installed a variety of racket extensions (Magic Racket and such), so the code is all nice and highlighted, none of the indentation works. For instance, a cond looks like this:

```
  (cond[]
   [])
```

Comment: I experimented with racket/scheme packages for VSCode too. Facing the same issue despite toggling various settings in Settings JSON file. The error is `There is no formatter for 'racket'-files installed.` when I press the "format" keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

magic-racket relies on the Racket language server, which got support for formatting (and fixing indentation) as of [this pr](https://github.com/jeapostrophe/racket-langserver/pull/24).